# Facebook Webhook challenge and token empty

Tags: php, facebook, get, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a very simple script sending an email if there is a new facebook comment.
I am using the Webhook: Application and the event: plugin_comment.
It actually works if I do not use and test the challenge and token.

I tried it as stated in the FB docs with:

```
$_GET['hub_verify_token']
$_GET['hub_challenge']
```

And I also tried:

```
$_REQUEST['hub_challenge']
$_REQUEST['hub_verify_token']
```

but its always empty.
If I disable the token check it works fine (also in production environment).

Comment: This is a step to be performed only once when you set up your webhook URL ...

Comment: thank you. Strange that is totally missing in the docs I was looking.

Comment: btw: Why would someone downvote the question?

Comment: Dunno what you read, but https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks#verification mentions this. _“Verification Requests -- We'll send you a GET request to verify your endpoint during setup, or when you update an existing topic subscription.”_